# Change html page background with select tag

Tags: html, image, select, background, dropdown

I am trying to change the html page background image (url image) when selecting from the drop down list, but I cannot find out how..
Below is my code:

```
<select id="styledSelect" onchange="doit()">
<option value="0" /> Select...
<option value="1" /> 1
<option value="2" /> 2
<option value="3" /> 3
<option value="4" /> 4
<option value="5" /> 5
<option value="6" /> 6
<option value="7" /> 7
<option value="8" /> 8
<option value="9" /> 9
</select>

<script>

function between(x, min, max) {
return x >= min && x <= max;
}

function doit() {

var s = document.getElementById('styledSelect');

if (between(s.value, 1, 3)) {
[http image1]
}
else if (between(s.value, 4, 6)) {
[http image2]
}
else if (between(s.value, 7, 9)) {
[http image3]
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just look the code below and you'll get in the right way.
(select just 1, 2 or 3, i didn't add other images, you can add when you need it)

```js
function between(x, min, max) {
  return x >= min && x <= max;
}

function doit() {

  var s = document.getElementById('styledSelect');
  
  if (between(s.value, 1, 3)) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i2.wp.com/ape-al.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/parallax-bg.jpg?fit=1600%2C730')";
  }
  else if (between(s.value, 4, 6)) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(LINK/PATH TO YOUR IMAGE);";
  }
  else if (between(s.value, 7, 9)) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(LINK/PATH TO YOUR IMAGE);";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="styledSelect" onchange="doit()">
  <option value="0" /> Select...
  <option value="1" /> 1
  <option value="2" /> 2
  <option value="3" /> 3
  <option value="4" /> 4
  <option value="5" /> 5
  <option value="6" /> 6
  <option value="7" /> 7
  <option value="8" /> 8
  <option value="9" /> 9
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: body  { 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

Comment: yes, you can do it, also you can add it dynamically with `document.body.style.backgroundSize = ...` take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp and I also suggest to use jQuery, it's much better to set things during runtime/dynamically

Comment: Also how can I insert "no-repeat " in the background command?

Comment: you can do it `backgroundRepeat="repeat-x"` or directly after the image: `url("path.png") no-repeat right top;`